# Need to bind to event after window is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my script that shows a container based on what anchor is given in the URL.

I have AJAX calls on the page which change the content.

The problem is that this "resets" the window and my function doesn't get fired again because it is bound to `document.ready`. Is there an event I can bind to  this that will trigger the first time the page is loaded and after the submit? 
The Ajax calls come fromt he CMS i am working on and i can't overwrite them.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = location.hash.replace('#', '');
    if (hash != '') {
        jQuery("." + hash).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Create some callback functions from your AJAX calls and put the page initialisation logic in there.

Comment: @Bladerxdxi If you include your AJAX call in your question, the above solution can be demonstrated.